# Metric topology: boundaries proof

Tags: analysis

I am stuck on what seems like a completely intuitive proof.

A is a subset of X. ( + for disjoint union)

I need to show, first, that

(i) Closure of S = interior of s + boundary of S

Then I am asked to show that

(ii) X =  interior of S + boundary of S + interior of the complement of S.

---

It's very understandable when you draw X and its subsets neatly on a piece of paper. But I don't know how to start this proof. Does it help that I have already shown earlier that

boundary of S = closure of S ∩ closure of the complement of S  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i), you know that that both the interior and boundary of $S$ are contained in its closure. Now, if $x$ is an interior point of $S$, then a small neighbourhood of $x$ is contained in the interior of $S$ as well. If $y$ is a boundary point of $S$, then every small neighbourhood of $y$ has some point outside of $S$. Can you see why these two conditions are mutually exclusive?

For (ii), you know $X=A\cup A^c$ for any subset $A$. Now let $A=\bar S$. Then
$$
X=\bar S\sqcup(\bar S)^c=\text{int}(S)\sqcup\partial S\sqcup(\bar S)^c.
$$
Now you need to prove that $(\bar S)^c=\text{int}(S^c)$. Try using De Morgan's laws on $\bar S$.

Comment: (ii) is absolutely clear now. I'm not completely sure I follow the last bits of (i). If e-neighbourhood of Y which is a boundary point of S intersects some S', then the boundary of S is not open in S. Therefore it is closed in S, so together with the interior forms a closure of S?